# Добавление полосы прокрутки к блоку div

Tags: html, css

Нашел очень много материала по цветовому оформлению. Но ни одного сайта, где бы рассказывалось о настройке ширины полосы прокрутки, отступов от нее до текста.
Кто делал, поделитесь опытом.

Answer (score 7):

Вот тебе [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/nM3Ks/). Это нужно? Полосу прокрутки менять тут нельзя. Это стандартный контрол операционной системы. Можно слепить что-то свое на javascript. Пример [тут](http://vimeo.com/35613552), смотри блок справа со списком видео. Используют, если нужна 100% стилизация всех элементов сайта. Отступ от полосы до текста регулируется свойством [padding](http://htmlbook.ru/css/padding), впрочем, как и до других границ: верх, низ, лево.

Добавлено. 
В [примере](http://vimeo.com/35613552) используется flash. Есть плагины jQuery для полос прокрутки, целых [10 штук](http://dwlessons.ru/jquery/10-plaginov-jquery-dlya-polos-prokrutki.html).

Comment: Интересно, про "слепить на javascript" есть готовые примеры... а то там, где вы показали, там, кажется, flash использовалось.

Comment: Ответ обновил.

Answer (score 1):

на js есть хороший пример [flexscroll](http://www.hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar)

Comment: Чем лучше других?

Answer (score 0):

Так можно поменять стандартный scrollbar

```
<style>
-webkit-scrollbar{height:10px}::-webkit-scrollbar{width:10px}::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:vertical{background-color:#3c3c3c}::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece:horizontal{background-color:#3c3c3c}::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical{background-color:#787878;border:1px #8f8f8f solid;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px}::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical:hover{background-color:#969696}::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical:active{background-color:#5b5b5b}::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal{background-color:#787878;border:1px #8f8f8f solid;border-radius:3px;-webkit-border-radius:3px}::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal:hover{background-color:#969696}::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:horizontal:active{background-color:#5b5b5b}::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal{background-color:#5e5e5e;background-repat:no-repeat;width:10px;height:10px}::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:hover{background-color:#747474;background-repat:no-repeat;width:10px;height:10px}::-webkit-scrollbar-button:horizontal:active{background-color:#6b6b6b;background-repat:no-repeat;width:10px;height:10px}::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical{background-color:#5e5e5e;background-repat:no-repeat;width:10px;height:10px}::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:hover{background-color:#747474;background-repat:no-repeat;width:10px;height:10px}::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:active{background-color:#6b6b6b;background-repat:no-repeat;width:10px;height:10px}::-webkit-resizer{background-color:#5e5e5e;background-repeat:no-repeat;width:5px;height:5px}::-webkit-resizer:hover{background-color:#747474;background-repeat:no-repeat;width:5px;height:5px}::-webkit-resizer:active{background-color:#6b6b6b;background-repeat:no-repeat;width:5px;height:5px}
</style>
```

Демо --> [Ссылка](http://streamcam.ru/)

Comment: Только это не кроссбраузерное решение и работать будет только на webkit-движке.